# Эффект металлика для маленьких блоков

Tags: css

Как передать эффект металлика (автомобильной красски) для относительно маленьких блоков (74x34).

P.S Не стоит кидать линк на мануал про градиент. Я прекрасно знаю, что именно им надо делать. Но я не могу подобрать необходимые значения, именно их от вас и жду.

Дополнения:
Меня интересует как лучше, с какой стороны, каким цветом передовать с какой прозрачностью.

Comment: А взять значения из фотошопа?

Comment: макета нету

Comment: А пример картинки можно?

Comment: http://tau.rghost.ru/47140639/image.png , вот так сейчас. Для светлых блоков сделал свой вариант металлика.

Answer (score 6):

Используй этот сайт [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). Там можно настроить)

Comment: Меня интересует как лучше, с какой стороны, каким цветом передовать с какой прозрачностью.

Comment: @HappyCougar так на колорзилле и посмотрите, как лучше. Я там в своё время тренировался.